# How to create Intellij Idea project from existing sources with meaningful module names?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module, structure, names

When I create a new project from existing sources in Idea, it just creates multiple modules with names like main1, main2 etc and splits main and test folders in maven-like project structure.

Could I still create an Idea project with nice module names and structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rearrange classes by dragging and dropping, or just changing the package statements.

Having a maven like project structure is advised as this convention is relied on by many frameworks i.e Junit.